Is it possible to start a specific code-block as folded by default
I have an org file which I'm using to tangle my init.el file. So this org file has a lot of code-blocks. Some of which are examples or useful reference or even Noweb References. So I would like code blocks like these to be folded by default when I open the file so that it helps in navigating the file.
I know that we can use the

org-hide-block-all  in an org mode hook like (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-hide-block-all) as mentioned in this answer OR
use the #+STARTUP: hideblocks to hide all code blocks in a specific file as mentioned in this answer.

But I'm looking for a way to target specific code-blocks to be folded.

Is this possible?
I'm also open to adding the code-block inside a drawer if it's natively possible to fold the drawer by default


I found this reddit post, but it doesn't have any solutions mentioned.

You could try putting them in different sections. It's possible to start with a section folded. I don't think you can do the same with individual code blocks, but I'm not sure.
